# JAVA 8 - Implementing Comparable in a user-defined class that uses generics - Collections.sort() not working

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, bounded-wildcard

I have a user-defined class that is supposed to be generic to accept Integers, Floats, Doubles, etc. but also needs to be able to be compared. It looks like:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<MyClass<T>>{
private T myClassObject;
...
```

And the compareTo method looks like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyClass<T> o){
    return this.myClassObject.compareTo((T) o));
}
```

Now in a later class that is supposed to be creating an ArrayList of MyClass objects and comparing them, I get:

```
sort(java.util.List<T>)' in 'java.util.Collections' cannot be applied to '(java.util.ArrayList<MyClass<?>>)
```

The ArrayList that holds these MyClass objects looks like:

```
ArrayList<MyClass<?>> temp = new ArrayList<MyClass<?>>();
```

Is it failing because of the wildcard generic use? Do I need to specify that ? extends Number or something else?

Comment: Just wondering: In your class definition you have `T myClassObj` in your compareTo method, you have `this.myClassObject` is this a typo or what is going on here?

Comment: It looks like the `compareTo` implementation should be `this.myClassObject.compareTo(o.myClassObject)`.

Comment: @ControlAltDel That was a typo, I'm sorry

Comment: @LouisWasserman That seems to be working syntax-wise, but do you know why I would not be able to use `Collections.sort` on an `ArrayList<MyClass<?>>`? This is where I am having trouble the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `T` in the `List<T>` parameter in the generic `Collections.sort` method, enforces that you pass in a list with elements that can be compared with each other.

A `List<MyClass<?>>` can have elements that are not comparable with each other.

With a `List<MyClass<?>>`, you can potentially put a `MyClass<String>` *and* a `MyClass<Integer>` into the same list!

```
ArrayList<MyClass<?>> temp = new ArrayList<MyClass<?>>();
temp.add(new MyClass<>(1));
temp.add(new MyClass<>("String"));
```

To sort this list, `Collections.sort` would have to know how to compare a `MyClass<Integer>` with a `MyClass<String>`! And that's nonsense. More importantly, `Comparable<T>` doesn't support this operation.

`List.sort` - a non-generic method - on the other hand, doesn't have this "equality constraint", and does a bunch of unsafe casts, and will throw an exception at runtime if you try to sort a list with different kinds of `MyClass`.

---

Though unrelated to the error, note that you implemented `Comparable` wrongly. It should be:

```
return myClassObject.compareTo(o.myClassObject);
```